# A proof of Radon–Nikodym theorem

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, radon-nikodym

I'm trying to fill in the details of the proof sketch given in my lecture note. This is to enforce where the assumptions are used.

> **Radon–Nikodym theorem:** Let $\mu, \nu$ be $\sigma$-finite measures on a measurable space $(X, \Sigma)$. If $\nu \ll \mu$ then there is a unique (up to a $\mu$-null set) $\Sigma$-measurable function $f:X \to [0, \infty)$ such that
> $$
> \nu (A) = \int_A f \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \Sigma.
> $$

Could you have a check on my attempt?

**Proof:**

1. We first assume $\mu, \nu$ are both **finite**.

- Existence:

Let $F$ be the collection of all $\Sigma$-measurable function $f:X \to [0, \infty]$ such that
$$
\int_A f \mathrm d \mu \le \nu(A) \quad \forall A \in \Sigma.
$$

Then $0 \in F$ and thus $F \neq \emptyset$. Let $(f_n) \subset F$ such that
$$
\lim_n \int_X f_n \mathrm d \mu = \sup_{f\in F} \int_X f \mathrm d \mu.
$$

It's easy to verify that if $f_1, f_2 \in F$ then $\max \{f_1, f_2\} \in F$. As such, we can assume $(f_n)$ is non-decreasing. Let
$$
g:= \lim_n f_n =\sup_n f_n.
$$

Then $g$ takes values in $[0, \infty]$ and is $\Sigma$-measurable. By [monotone convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4271552/an-elegant-proof-of-monotone-convergence-theorem), $g \in F$. We define a measure $\nu_0$ by
$$
\nu_0 (A) := \nu(A) - \int_A g \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \Sigma.
$$

Then $\nu_0$ is **non-negative**. We claim that $\nu_0 = 0$. Assume the contrary that $\nu_0 (X)>0$. Because $\mu$ is **finite**, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$
\nu_0(X) > \varepsilon \mu(X).
$$

Let $(P, N)$ be a [Hahn decomposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440186/hahn-decomposition-of-measure) of the signed measure $\nu_0 - \varepsilon \mu$. We claim that $\mu(P)>0$. If not, $\mu(P) = \nu(P)=0$ because $\nu \ll \mu$. Then $\nu_0 (P) \le \nu(P) = 0$ and we get a contradiction $(\nu_0 - \varepsilon \mu) (X) = (\nu_0 - \varepsilon \mu) (N) \le 0$. Let $g' := g + \varepsilon 1_P$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
\nu(A) - \int_A g' \mathrm d\mu &= \nu_0 (A) -\int_A \varepsilon 1_P \mathrm d\mu \\
&= \nu_0 (A) - \varepsilon \mu (A \cap P) \\
&\ge \nu_0 (A \cap P) - \varepsilon \mu (A \cap P) \\
&= (\nu_0 - \varepsilon \mu) (A) \ge 0.
\end{align}
$$

Also,
$$
\int_A g' \mathrm d\mu - \int_A g \mathrm d\mu = \varepsilon \mu(P) >0.
$$

This contradicts the maximality of $g$. As such,
$$
\nu(A) = \int_A g \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \Sigma.
$$

Because $\nu$ is **finite**, $\nu(X) < \infty$ and thus $g$ is $\mu$-integrable. This implies $\{g = \infty\}$ is a $\mu$-null set. As such, we obtain the required $f$ by re-defining $g$ as follows, i.e.,
$$
f(x)= \begin{cases}
g(x) & \text {if } g(x)<\infty \\
0 & \text {otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

- Uniqueness:

Let $f':X \to [0, \infty)$ be another function that satisfies the required properties. Let $A := \{f> f'\}$ and $B := \{f< f'\}$. Then $A, B \in \Sigma$. Hence
$$
\nu(A) = \int_A f \mathrm d\mu = \int_A f' \mathrm d\mu \quad \text{and} \quad \nu(B) = \int_B f \mathrm d\mu = \int_B f' \mathrm d\mu.
$$

It follows that
$$
\int_A (f-f') \mathrm d\mu = \int_B (f'-f) \mathrm d\mu =0.
$$

As such, $A, B$ are $\mu$-null sets.

2. $\mu, \nu$ are $\sigma$-finite.

There is a partition $(A_n) \subset \Sigma$ of $X$ such that $\mu(A_n), \nu(A_n) < \infty$ for all $n$. Apply above result, we get $(f_n)$ with $f_n: A_n \to [0, \infty)$ being $\Sigma$-measurable such that
$$
\nu(A \cap A_n) = \int_{A \cap A_n} f_n \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \Sigma.
$$

We can extend $f_n$ to the whole $X$ by re-defining $f_n$ as follows, i.e.,
$$
f_n'(x)= \begin{cases}
f_n(x) & \text {if } x\in A_n \\
0 & \text {otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Then
$$
\nu(A \cap A_n) = \int_{A} f'_n \mathrm d \mu \quad \forall A \in \Sigma.
$$

By monotone convergence theorem, we get
$$
\nu(A) = \int_A \sum_n f'_n \mathrm d\mu \quad \forall A \in \Sigma.
$$

Let $f : = \sum_n f'_n$. Notice that $f$ takes values in $[0, \infty)$. Because each $f_n$ is unique (up to a $\mu$-null set), so is $f$. This completes the proof.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't read it all yet, but, the theorem is valid if $\nu$ is a signed measure too iirc. You might (or might not) want to see if you can add that generality

Comment: You said $A$ and $B$ are $\mu$ -null sets above the second cases, I think it is not valid. You can instead say $f$ and $f'$ are identical almost surely.